VS2022: Watch Window defaulting to value not in DebuggerDisplayAttribute
Simple problem.  I have a class, with multiple properties.  I have overridden ToString() and created a protected method called "DebugDisplay" that returns a string.
I have applied the [DebuggerDisplay("{DebugDisplay()}")] attribute to the class.
I build, and in the Watch Window i get:  "myVar | EntityImplementation = None"
EntityImplementation is a property returning a custom enum, that does exist on myVar, but it isn't in the ToString() result, or the DebugDisplay() method result.
I have completely removed this property and all references, and suddenly VS uses the correct watch value that i'm returning in my DebugDisplay() method.
I re-added (by undoing the commented out code) the EntityImplmentation property, and suddenly my DebugDisplay is completely overwridden again.
What is going on here?
